# How to install guest additions on Tails?

Tags: tails, virtual-machine

I'm running tails on virtualbox and for the life of me i really cant install guest additions. I keep getting `Could not mount the media/drive 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED).`

I have tried creating a new optical drive and leaving it empty, when i hit Devices>Insert Guest Additions CD image nothing happens. When I click again I get that error. I've tried many other ways in the terminal and its still not working. I really need it for the copy and paste function can anyone help?

Comment: You should try asking on the SuperUser stack exchange. There might be someone there who can help.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's kinda late, but have you tried interchanging the virtual optical drive Tails is mounted and the empty one? Let's suppose you have 2 empty virtual optical drives in your machine, try mounting Tails to each one of the them. If that step is successful, boot in Tails and set up an Administration Password by clicking the '+' sign. Insert the VBox-Guest Additions and open the File Manager by doucle-clicking the Home icon on Desktop. You should see VBox_GAs_6 in the left side of the window (/media/amnesia/VBox_GAs_6*). Open it and double-click the Run Software button on the top of the window. Click run when prompted and provide the root pasword you set up earlier during boot. That's it.